# Why native API is called when I/O buffer gets empty?

Tags: java, iostream, bufferedreader

I am reading java tutorial about Streams and I/O. where I came across a statement that says ..

`Buffered input streams read data from a memory area known as a buffer; the native input API is called only when the buffer is empty. Similarly, buffered output streams write data to a buffer, and the native output API is called only when the buffer is full.`

[Here is the source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html)

Here **why the Native APIs are called only when the buffer is empty**?  if so, what is the need of calling API on empty buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Most of the examples we've seen so far use unbuffered I/O. 
>       This means each read or write request is handled directly by the underlying OS. 
>       This can make a program much less efficient, since each such request often triggers 
>       disk access, network activity, or some other operation that is relatively expensive.

This statement in the same document gives answer to your question. Native APIs are APIs of OS available with OS to execute input / output tasks. Your programming language is a layer above OS to interact with those APIs and buffered streams are created to use these Native APIs efficiently.

As MadProgrammer mentioned in comments below, Native APIs are called only when buffer is empty:

1- Because the results are buffered in memory and native calls are needed to acces resources like Hard-disk when nothing is buffered in memory(or RAM)

2- To reduce the overhead. Native calls are expensive operations

Comment: Why they are called only when the buffer is empty ? @Guanxi

Comment: @MaheshVarma 1- Because the results are buffered in memory; 2- To reduce the overhead.  Native calls are expensive operations

Answer (score 1):

> JVM needs to call a native method to ask the operating system to get
>   data from the file system. This applies to all input, not just to
>   buffered streams.Native methods are required to ask the operating
>   system to put data into the file system.